# Check if selected values of a dropdownlist is matching static value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form where dropdownlists are generated dynamically

```
<c:forEach var="companyList" items="${company.detailList}" varStatus="status">
<tr>
<td>c:out value="${companyList.employeeName}" /></td>
<td>
<select name="employeeList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.value">
    <option>No Record found</option>
    <option>Record available in year 2000</option>
    <option>Record available in year 2010</option>
    <option>Record available in year 2015</option>
    <option>Record available in year 2016</option>
    <option>Record available in year 2017</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="EvalComments">Evaluator Comments</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="evalComments"><c:out value="${companyList.comments}"></c:out></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Complete employee evaluation</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

lets say 6 rows are generated in this case and if all the selections in the dropdownlist matches to *"No Record found"*.While clicking the submit button , validation should be performed at javascript whether all the selections matches to no records found .If the validation fails , evaluator needs to enter the evaluation comments before submission.

Currently i am not able to do the get the array of dropdownlist selections and compare with a static value.

Any help and support is appreciated .

thanks for valuable time

Comment: `$(select).val()` <- you can only select one option

Comment: @adeneo That is so [`!true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple).

Comment: Show what are you doing to compare?

Comment: Going by the code i will have 6 dropdownlists with different ids employeeList[0].value to employeeList[6].value.so i need to get this array of this selections in javascript and get the individual selected values to compare with no records found.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - it is when the posted select has no `multiple` attribute

Comment: @adeneo I agree, but when typing *"you can only select one option"* I'd still have the tendency of adding *"without the `multiple` attribute"*, just to make sure people with less experience don't misinterpret.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the selected value of a drop-down list using jQuery as shown below.

```
var val = $('#employeeList1 Option:selected').val();
```

Then it is easy to compare.

```
if(val == "No Record found")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').on('change',function(){
var test = $(this).val();
if(test==1){
alert('banana');}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```